# Flask and passenger setup?

Tags: flask, passenger-apache

Looking for best practices advice on deploying a Flask app.  My hosting provider has `passenger` available. I have a basic structure of:

```
~/home/me/dev.domain.com
└── public
    └── cgi-bin
    └── ...
```

The hosting company tells me that I need a `passenger_wsgi.py` at the level of the `public` dir.

My project roughly looks like:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   ├── images
│   │   └── js
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── layout.html
│   │   ├── main.html
│   │   └── other.html
│   └── views
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── main.py
└── app.py
```

My question is: Where should the `venv` live? Inside the `public` folder or at the same level as `public`

```
~/home/me/dev.domain.com
└── passenger_wsgi.py
└── venv
└── public
    ├── app
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── static
    │   ├── templates
    │   └── views
    └── app.py
```

or

```
~/home/me/dev.domain.com
└── passenger_wsgi.py
└── public
    ├── venv
    ├── app
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── static
    │   ├── templates
    │   └── views
    └── app.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the following working:

My question was about the project layout to make deployment easier. My current solution is

```
$ tree -d
.
+-- passenger_wsgi.py
+-- public
¦   +-- static
¦   ¦   +-- LIB
¦   ¦   +-- css
¦   ¦   +-- images
¦   ¦   +-- js
¦   +-- templates
¦   +-- views
+-- requirements.txt
+-- venv
```

Basically, I renamed the default Flask `app` folder to `public`.  My `passenger_wsgi.py` script now looks like:

```
import os
import sys

INTERP = os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'venv/bin/python3')

if sys.executable != INTERP:
    os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

from public import create_app

cwd = os.path.abspath('.')
sys.path.append(cwd)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(cwd, '/public'))  # You must add your project here

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(cwd, 'venv/bin'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(cwd, 'venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/'))

application = create_app()
```

It looks like the contents and operation of a `passenger_wsgi.py` file is hosting platform dependant. I had to make sure that my `venv` for the site was in my path before I did anything else.  This looks nothing like the example in my provider's FAQ.